# Android SeekBar not working in onCreateView

Tags: android, seekbar

in my MainActivity onCreateView i create a seek bar programatically (no xml) like this:

```
        mVolControlSB = new SeekBar(context);
        mVolControlSB.setMax(maxVolume);
        mVolControlSB.setProgress(curVolume);
        mVolControlSB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "volControlSB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener onStopTrackingTouch arg0="+arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "volControlSB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener onStartTrackingTouch arg0="+arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1, 0);
        }
    });
    mVolControlSB.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 20));
    kitctrlLayout.addView(mVolControlSB);
```

it displays the seek bar but the thumb position is in the wrong place (maxVolume is 15 and curVolume is 10 in my example but it shows all the way to the left). also, the callbacks aren't been called when i drag the thumb, nothing happens. i make mVolControlSB a static field in the MainActivity class but i also tried it as a local

```
static  SeekBar mVolControlSB;
```

does anyone have an idea?

note, i should add that i'm using tab layout and this code is called inside

```
        public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

thanks

Comment: Try to set `mVolControlSB.setProgress(arg1);` in your `onProgressChanged` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine for me like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay);

    mVolControlSB = new SeekBar(this);
    mVolControlSB.setMax(15);
    mVolControlSB.setProgress(10);
    mVolControlSB
            .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity",
                            "volControlSB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener onStopTrackingTouch arg0="
                                    + arg0.getProgress());
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity",
                            "volControlSB.setOnSeekBarChangeListener onStartTrackingTouch arg0="
                                    + arg0.getProgress());
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1,
                        boolean arg2) {

                }
            });
    mVolControlSB.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ll.addView(mVolControlSB);
}
```

Comment: looks like the code is the same as mine but my view is in a tab layout, so i create the layout inside public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment . maybe that's the problem?

Comment: that worked, the key here was in the layout params, i used WRAP_CONTENT for the width which was wrong, you used MATCH_PARENT which made it the right width, and the callbacks were working, i just didn't see them because there was not where to drag it. thanks

Comment: @Jignesh I am facing issue with SeekBar can you please help me... here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54692981/android-music-seekbar-is-not-working-idle